# Why did deprecate method locations in @ConfigurationProperties?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I'm trying to configure multiple '.yml' in spring boot like...

application.yml

```
spring:
    profile: local
```

api.yml

```
spring:
    profile: local
myapi:
  url: localhost/...
```

So, I found locations method in @ConfigurationProperties. 
but, It was deprecated in 1.4.x

```
Deprecated. as of 1.4 in favor of configuring the environment directly with additional locations
```

How could I configuring this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`spring.config.name`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) to change the configuration file names that will be looked for. Multiple names can be configured using a comma-separated list. In your case, you'd want to set it to `application,api`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working in all of our `@SpringBootTest` classes since the property `spring.config.name` is not being set. The alternative would be to set it explicitly in all the annotated test classes via `properties` attribute. But to me this seems inefficient. Do you have a solution that works with tests as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a common superclass that sets it or a ContextCustomizer that adds a PropertySource to the application context's environment

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: The issue with this is that i may want to use configuration in third modules, so they can be injected using IoC with annotations, this new way makes the client app to know explicitly which are the configuration to be loaded